# Select elements which don't have a given class as parent

Tags: jquery

I have some html like this

```
<div class="asd">
    <audio src="...">
</div>

<audio src="...">
<audio src="...">
<audio src="...">
```

Now I need to select all of the audio elements, that don't have a parent, which has a class `asd`. 
I tried something like

```
$('audio').not('.asd');
```

But it returns all the audio elements.

How can I do it?

Comment: You can do it with jquery (see https://api.jquery.com/parent/). Please show some effort to solve the problem yourself and tell us where you got stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:not`:

```
$('audio:not(.asd audio)')
```

Or `.not()`:

```
$('audio').not('.asd audio')
```

```js
var $audio = $('audio:not(.asd audio)');

console.log($audio.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="asd">
    <audio src="..." />
</div>

<audio src="..." />
<audio src="..." />
<audio src="..." />
```

Comment: oh sorry, it worked, I didn't try it with audio as the second criteria in the 'not' as I couldn't understand the logic behind that